# How to chain Coroutine Flow?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I could easily chain `coroutine` `Flow`s by doing:

```
val someFlow = flow { //Some logic that my succeed or throw error }
val anotherFlow = flow { // Another logic that my succeed or throe error }

val resultingFlow = someFlow.flatmapLatest(anotherFlow)
```

but what if I want to individually be able to retry `someFlow` and `anotherFlow` where if `someFlow` already succeed to return a value but `anotherFlow` failed, I want to retry `anotherFlow` by using the value from `someFlow` (The value return when it succeeded).

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `retryWhen` operator on `anotherFlow` like this:

```
val someFlow = flow { 
    //Some logic that my succeed or throw error 
}

val anotherFlow = flow { 
    // Another logic that my succeed or throe error 
}
.retryWhen { cause, attempt ->
    if (cause is IOException) {    // retry on IOException
        emit(“Some value”)         // emit anything you want before retry
        delay(1000)                // delay for one second before retry
        true
    } else {                       // do not retry otherwise
        false
    }
}

val resultingFlow = someFlow.flatmapLatest(anotherFlow)
```

Just be careful because you could end up retrying forever. Use the `attempt` argument to check the number of times you have retried.

Here is the `retryWhen` operator official documentation: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/retry-when.html

Comment: This would automatically retry the request but what if I only want to retry if (for example) a button is clicked?

Comment: Make sure the job where the flow is running is completed and start another job/coroutine with the flow.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones for your use case, you can use suspendCancellableCoroutine and resume continuation on click of button through callback

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `zip`? 
I haven't tested or anything but this might be worth a try.

```
val someFlow = flow {}
val anotherFlow = flow {}
someFlow.zip(anotherFlow) { some, another ->
    if(another is Resource.Error)
        repository.fetchAnother(some)
    else
        some
}.collect {
    Log.d(TAG, it)
}
```